# Phpmyadmin cant create table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a new database for a quiz project.
Now I ran into a strange error and never seen anything like it before.

I'm trying to add a table named : `questions`.

After that I'm only trying to give it 4 columns.

```
"id => int, name => varchar, question_id => int and awnser_id => int
```

Now my exact query is as follow;

```
CREATE TABLE `playquzi`.`quiz` 
( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`question_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
`awnser_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

After that I receive the following error

## 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

I did put `id` as `primary`

Comment: You are trying to add a table named Questions but you CREATE TABLE statement says 'Quiz'. Is that correct? And what the others say, you are missing the primary key.

Comment: @massie Yes I am, I just noticed the query generated is incorrect. It seems that the generated query indeed does not put the ID as a primary key eventhough I did say it should be.

Comment: Are you using the phpMyAdmin graphical table creation tool?  What phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` column have to be the primary key of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE `playquzi`.`quiz` 
( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
`question_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
`awnser_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: No idea how I just missed that, I did check the box to make it the primary key, looks like it's not added into the query. Any suggestions what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear. Your autoincrement column must be specified as a key.

```
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Auto-Incrementing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) id field to be Primary Key at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE playquzi.quiz 
( 
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    question_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    awnser_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```